# Source Tree - can "reset master to this commit" revert the pushed commit?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Source Tree.

I have 2 remote branchs which are dev and master.
I always make changes in dev branch and merge the change to master branch.
But I have accidentally been using master branch to make changes instead of dev branch and then push the commit to the remote.

I have found that if I click the last merge message, there is option "reset master to this commit".
Should I use this function to erase the last commit and go back the original point?

If yes, what reset types should I use so that I can keep my changes in local, and then stash it for dev branch to apply?

And Is there Source Tree way to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the `hard` mode, which is equivalent to `git reset --hard <the-last-merge-commit>`. The local master will point at the last merge commit. And then run `git push origin -f master` to update `master` in the remote repository.

To apply the commit onto `develop`, you can switch to `develop` first and then use `git cherry-pick $commit`. Here the commit is the one you mistakenly created on `master`. Although it's not on `master` now, it's still in the local repository and can be manipulated by git commands including `git cherry-pick`.